# SqlServerCe 4.0 "Database already opened by a different user" Error

Tags: sql-server-ce, webmatrix

I am working with a SqlServerCe 4.0 database located in an Asp.Net app's /App_Data/ folder - in this case hosted by IISExpress via WebMatrix.  The database is also accessed from a Microsoft WebMatrix Extension - which runs in the WebMatrix.exe process.  Either the WebMatrix Extension or the Asp.Net app can access the database just fine as long as each is the first to access - in the case the accessing app is the second to open a connection, the following error is returned:

```
Database already opened by a different user. [ Db name = ... ] :    at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection.ProcessResults(Int32 hr)
   at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection.Open(Boolean silent)
   at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection.Open()
```

The code opening the connection from the WebMatrix Extension is:

```
SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection("DataSource=" + dbPath + "\\App_Data\\db.sdf");
conn.Open();
SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand("select ...", conn);
SqlCeDataReader r = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Which throws the exception on the **conn.Open()** line.

I am running the latest SqlServerCe 4.0 bits and have tried running WebMatrix as Administrator, but the result is consistent with the above.  There is precious little in terms of search results for this.

-Paul

Comment: Are you using the exact same connection string for both apps?

Comment: No, they are different, using different providers:

the WebMatrix Extension uses:  

    SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection("DataSource=" + dbPath + "\\App_Data\\db.sdf");

the Asp.Net app uses the web.config format:

    <add key="umbracoDbDSN" value="datalayer=SQLCE4Umbraco.SqlCEHelper,SQLCE4Umbraco;data source=|DataDirectory|\db.sdf" />

But, it seems to me, that it makes no difference as I can reproduce the behavior throwing the "Database already opened by a different user" exception from either connection by first opening a prior connection.  

-Paul

Comment: Please test with the exact same full file path on both connection strings.

Comment: Eric - Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately I see the same behavior.  Using the string "data source=C:\Users\paul\Documents\My Web Sites\site\App_Data\db.sdf" when I set the Asp.Net app's connection string to the same in the WebMatrix Extension.  When I remove the WebMatrix Extension, the Asp.Net app can connect as expected.  I will try will full IIS next to rule out IIS Express as the culprit.